# Don't print all slots of class instance by default

Tags: r, class, inheritance, matrix, r-s4

I wrote class that extends matrix by adding one slot for history of operations done on given matrix.

```
setClass("newMatrix", representation(history = "character"),  contains = "matrix")
```

I want instances of this class to act as matrices, so I want only .Data slot to be printed out by default, and history to be called by function.

```
m <- new("newMatrix", 1:4, 2, 2, history = "ipsum")
> m
An object of class "newMatrix"
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
Slot "history":
[1] "ipsum"
```

Is there a way to make R print by default only .Data slot of this class, like this:

```
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're in a S4 setting, the best way is to define a show method:

```
setClass("newMatrix", representation(history = "character"),  contains = "matrix")
m <- new("newMatrix", 1:4, 2, 2, history = "ipsum")

setMethod("show",
          "newMatrix",
          function(object){
            show(object@.Data)
          })
```

If you need a separate `print` method, you also need to provide an S4 method for that. The classic construct to avoid S3/S4 conflicts, is the following:

```
print.newMatrix <- function(x, ...){
 print(x@.Data)

}

setMethod("print",
          "newMatrix",
          print.newMatrix)
```

Constructing a separate `print` method is not really necessary, as `print()` will use the `show()` method here if it can't find a `print` method for the class `newMatrix`.

You could create only the S3 method, but that can get you into trouble as explained on the help page `?Methods_for_S3`

( see : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.4.3/topics/Methods_for_S3 )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a `print` method for your class:

```
print.newMatrix <- function(x, ...) {
  print.default(x@.Data, ...)
}

> print(m)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Comment: That is advised against in the documentation of the `methods` package itself (see my answer).

Comment: Yes, just that from what he showed in the question, this is a sufficient answer for his problem. It is still nice of you to give him the extra guidance in case.

Comment: what he showed in the question, is an S4 class. Your solution can go wrong by simply loading a package. And as S4 classes only make sense in the context of creating your own package, following the guidelines laid out by R itself seems like a smart idea ;-)\